# Laravel attribute with default value is set, still gives an error Integrity constraint violation 'priority' cannot be null

Tags: sql, laravel, migration, constraints, integrity

Migration:

```
$table->tinyInteger('priority')->default(1);
```

Controller Method:

```
  /**
   * Store a newly created resource in storage.
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
   * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
   */
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
    //
    $this->validate($request, [
      'asset_type' => 'required',
      'scan_time' => 'required|numeric',
      'priority' => 'nullable|numeric',
    ]);

    $data = $request->except('_token');
    
    try {
      ScanProfile::add($data);
      return back()->with('success', 'Scan Profile has been added');
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
      throw $th;
      return back()->withErrors([$th->getMessage()]);
    }
  }
```

Model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'system_name', 'key', 'scan_time', 'priority'
  ];


  /**
   * Create new scan profile
   *
   * @param array $data
   * @param UploadedFile $photo 
   * @return void
   */
  public static function add($data, $photo)
  {
    $sp = new ScanProfile();
    $sp->fill($data);

    try {
      $sp->save();
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
      throw new Exception("Error in save : " . $th->getMessage(), 1);
    }
  }
```

Data:

```
$data = [
  "priority" => null
  "system_name" => "Ultra Scan"
  "asset_type" => "D"
  "scan_time" => "3"
]
```

Error:

Error in save : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'priority' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `master_scan_profiles` (`priority`, `system_name`, `asset_type`, `scan_time`, `id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, Ultra Scan, D, 3, 843a3073-d087-4e49-9280-5c3d6be025d6, 2021-11-25 07:31:06, 2021-11-25 07:31:06))

Answer (score 1):

because in your validation rules you say:

```
'priority' => 'nullable|numeric',
```

so, a priority with null value would pass ...
to avoid this , you can use [filled](https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/laravel-validation-filled-example) validation

```
$this->validate($request, [
      'asset_type' => 'required',
      'scan_time' => 'required|numeric',
      'priority' => 'filled|numeric',
    ]);
```

Comment: Changed 'priority' => 'nullable|numeric', to 'priority' => 'filled|numeric', Now getting validation error says: The priority field must have a value.

Comment: yes, because you pass it as null, the validation validate the if the priority  present is should not be null, so you either pass it with a value, or you should not pass it at all

Comment: Yes, I get to know that and the issue was solved. thanks btw. @OMR